# Find Files in Folder - Search Query Includes Parentheses

Tags: power-automate

I have a flow that pulls a list of filenames from an Excel file and then looks for them in a folder. Sometimes the filenames have parentheses in them, which causes issues with the search query and it doesn't even look for the file. I'm not sure how to handle the parentheses, but I don't want to remove the parentheses from the filenames (and ergo the search query). I thought about trimming the parentheses from the search query, but I want to make sure the right file is found. Perhaps I just need a way to escape the parentheses? I'm not sure how to do that though.

Here's a picture of the flow section in question:

[image]

I tried to find another post on this but after searching for a while I couldn't find anything, so I'm sorry if this has been answered already!

Any help is appreciated!

Edit: I'm going to try replacing any parentheses found with %28/%29 per Expiscornovus' suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use a different search mode in the settings of your Find Files in Folder action (OneDriveSearch instead of Pattern)?

Ignore my previous suggested encoding. Inputting the Search query with parentheses should work. Look at the example below.

[image]

Comment: I have not, but I'm not sure if I can. Maybe I can do a replace... The search query is just the filename value, that's all. So you might still be right, if I replace any parentheses found with url encoding. I'll try it.

Comment: @sassbearilla, in Power Automate you have an expression language. One of the functions is encodeUriComponent. I have added an example on how you could use this function.

Comment: how do I apply that to the Filename, though? I know there's a way to apply expressions to the dynamic content itself, i.e., encodeUriComponent(('Apply_to_each')['Filename']).

Comment: Nevermind, encodeUriComponent(items('Apply_to_each')?['Filename']) works. But so does encodeUriComponent(Apply_to_each()?['Filename']), lol, so I'm not sure what the difference is.

Comment: You could use encodeUriComponent(items('Apply_to_each')?['Filename']) or encodeUriComponent(item()?['Filename']) within an apply to each loop. These are just different functions which both return the Filename property of the current item.

Comment: That's still not working... I realized that I found that using the Pattern search mode worked better originally, but with encodeUriComponent, OneDriveSearch works better, but not perfectly. It looks like the issue with that is apostrophes, lol. I just can't win!

Comment: Can you share an example of a filename you are trying to find? Let me try and see if I can reproduce the issue with that same Find files in folder action. This way I might be able to find a fix or a workaround.

Comment: Nothing too crazy. The two types I'm having issues with are basically in this format:
Kwik E Mart (7 Eleven) Statement.pdf
Applebee's Statement.pdf

I've reduced my Flow to just listing the rows in the spreadsheet, then apply to each --> find file in folder w/ uriComponent(items('Apply_to_each')['filename']) (OneDriveSearch, not Pattern now), then printing the name of the file found in an adjacent column to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the examples. I tried to reproduce the issue. Without encoding the OneDriveSearch works fine for me. It finds the Kwik E Mart (7 Eleven) statement.pdf.

Btw, the Pattern Search mode means using a RegEx query value. 

I will update my answer.

Comment: Hmm... Now it's got me wondering if it's because the search query is coming from Excel, and maybe something is getting lost in translation. I need to look at the raw input...

Comment: Yes, I did not try that in my repro. Good idea to have a look at the raw input and output of the Excel action 